# Checking that TextBox.Text.Length is between 1 and 10

Tags: vb.net, textbox, string-length

I am trying to validate the number of characters placed inside a `TextBox` but am having some trouble. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
If Not ((TextBox5.Text.Length) <= 1) Or ((TextBox5.Text.Length) >= 10) Then
            MsgBox("Invalid date entry. Use the the following format: DD-MM-YYYY.")
            TextBox5.Focus()
            TextBox5.SelectAll()
Else
    'do whatever
End If
```

What I want is for `TextBox5` to have a length between (and inclusive) 1 and 10,  if not reselect the `TextBox` making it ready for another user input.

The code responds well for an input less than 1 but fails to recognise any input larger than 10 characters. I can't see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Not` part

Comment: You said "If it's not below 2 or above 9", every number 2 or above will pass the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't call `Focus`.  The documentation clearly states, don't call `Focus`.  If you want to focus a control, you call its `Select` method.

You don't need to call either though.  You should be handling the `Validating` event and if the control fails validation, you set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the control will not lose focus in the first place.

```
If myTextBox.TextLength < 1 OrElse myTextBox.TextLength > 10 Then
    'Validation failed.
    myTextBox.SelectAll()
    e.Cancel = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, this should do the trick.
**NOTE** There are a few different ways to achieve this task, however from there sample code you have shown, this should be fine.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox5.Text.Length < 1 Or TextBox5.Text.Length > 10 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid date entry. Use the the following format: DD-MM-YYYY.")
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("date accepted...")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have this triggering from a button click event.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you must do:

1. on properties set to maxlength=10 and
2. handle on KeyPressEventArgs

like this:

```
Private Sub res_pin_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles res_pin.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
            If Me.res_pin.Text.Length < 6 Then
                e.Handled = True
            Else
                Me.res_deposit.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```